# How to fix reverse proxy nginx with shiny-server

Tags: django, nginx, shiny, shiny-server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I cannot get my shiny app to render javascript with django through my nginx reverse proxy. For example, dynamic graphs will not display but the HTML and CSS sliders will. Do I have my nginx config set up correctly?

I am trying to display my shiny applications that are served via shiny server in the srv/shiny-server directory. I have been following along with this tutorial http://pawamoy.github.io/2018/03/15/django-auth-server-for-shiny/#try-it-with-a-dockerized-project .

I have changed the shny-server.conf to listen on port 8100.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas of how to get the shiny app rendering correctly ?

Thanks!

Nginx Settings:

```
    # declare your Django app
    upstream djangoapp_server {
        server localhost:8000;
    }

    # declare your Shiny app
    upstream shinyapp_server {
        server localhost:8100;
    }

    # required for WebSockets
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        # normal requests go to Django
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://djangoapp_server;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://djangoapp_server;
                break;
            }
        }

        # "shinyTest" requests go to Shiny
        location ~ /shinyTest/.+ {

            rewrite ^/shinyTest/(.*)$ /$1 break;

            proxy_pass http://shinyapp_server;
            proxy_redirect http://shinyapp_server/ $scheme://$host/shinyTest/;

            # required for WebSockets
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_read_timeout 20d;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

    }
```

Django Template
template/shinytest.html

```
    {% load i18n static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
        <link href="{% static "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

          <section id="content">
            <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('{% url "shiny_contents" %}', function (data) {
                  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                  $('#content').append(iframe);
                  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
                  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(data.html_contents);
                  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();




                  // Attempt circumvention
                  if (iframe.contentWindow.WebSocket)
                      WebSocket = iframe.contentWindow.WebSocket;
                });
              });

            </script>
          </section
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Django Template

```
    def shinyTest(request):
        return render(request, 'djangoShinyBeta/shinyTest.html')

    def shiny_contents(request):
        response = requests.get('http://localhost:8100/shinyapp/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        return JsonResponse({'html_contents': str(soup)})
```

I think the request is proxied correctly because the static assets are loaded. The one thing that is not rendering is the graph. My shiny app is served via shiny-server in srv/shiny-server/shinyapp. I am able to fully access it via http://localhost:8100/shinyapp/.

Something else to be noted is that if I serve up the app with

```
sudo R -e "shiny::runApp(appDir='shinyapp', port=8100)
```

and change the shiny_contents view to 
​

```
def shiny_contents(request):
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:8100')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    return JsonResponse({'html_contents': str(soup)})
```

​

The shiny app renders correctly.

[image: Screenshot of reverse proxy not working]

[image: Screenshot of Console]

Comment: Could be a problem with the WebSocket if only the graph doesn't show up. Don't you have any error messages, either in the browser console or in the R process output? Are the only user? Are you using Docker and docker-compose? Also, didn't you already find the solution? Your second `shiny_contents` view is the correct one, just like in the tuto. When you `requests.get` on `localhost:8100`, you don't pass through NginX, so you must not use the `/shinyapp/` sub-URL.